# Draw geometric shapes in c++ without using opengl

Tags: c++, shapes

I'm looking for a simple library that can create and draw some geometric shapes without using openGL or directX and also have documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just gdi would be enough i guess
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-ellipse?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

You could use any GUI library, like Gtk, Qt, Motif, etc. ...
If you are on Linux, you could draw on screen directly with X11.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of 2D graphics library, but under the hood most of them use OpenGL, so technically you still use OpenGL but not directly (which is probably what you meant).

Some of them:

- SFML
- SDL
- Skia
- Cairo

As frederic mentioned you can also use some GUI libraries, since most of them have something like Canvas (the name can vary) which allows to draw shapes very easily.